# Mongo transation exception when using the latest Spring Data Mongo reactive

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor

When I tried the transaction feature with Mongo 4 and the latest Spring Data Mongo Reactive, I got the failure like this.

```
18:57:22.823 [main] ERROR org.mongodb.driver.client - Callback onResult call produced an error
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientImpl$1.onResult(MongoClientImpl.java:90)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientImpl$1.onResult(MongoClientImpl.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$2.onResult(ClientSessionHelper.java:80)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$2.onResult(ClientSessionHelper.java:73)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster$ServerSelectionRequest.onResult(BaseCluster.java:433)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.handleServerSelectionRequest(BaseCluster.java:297)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.selectServerAsync(BaseCluster.java:157)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.selectServerAsync(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper.createClientSession(ClientSessionHelper.java:68)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientImpl.startSession(MongoClientImpl.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoClientImpl$1.apply(MongoClientImpl.java:153)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoClientImpl$1.apply(MongoClientImpl.java:150)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.SingleResultCallbackSubscription.requestInitialData(SingleResultCallbackSubscription.java:38)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.tryRequestInitialData(AbstractSubscription.java:153)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.request(AbstractSubscription.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ObservableToPublisher$1$1.request(ObservableToPublisher.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:102)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onSubscribe(MonoProcessor.java:399)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ObservableToPublisher$1.onSubscribe(ObservableToPublisher.java:39)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.SingleResultCallbackSubscription.<init>(SingleResultCallbackSubscription.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.Observables$2.subscribe(Observables.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ObservableToPublisher.subscribe(ObservableToPublisher.java:36)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromPublisher.subscribe(MonoFromPublisher.java:43)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3555)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.add(MonoProcessor.java:531)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.subscribe(MonoProcessor.java:444)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7677)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:7841)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7670)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7634)
    at com.example.demo.DataInitializer.init(DataInitializer.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:261)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
    at com.example.demo.Application.main(Application.java:24)
```

I used a initialization class to initialize this class.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
class DataInitializer {

    private final ReactiveMongoOperations mongoTemplate;

    public DataInitializer(ReactiveMongoOperations mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @EventListener(value = ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void init() {
        log.info("start data initialization  ...");
        this.mongoTemplate.inTransaction()
            .execute(
                s ->
                    Flux
                        .just("Post one", "Post two")
                        .flatMap(
                            title -> s.insert(Post.builder().title(title).content("content of " + title).build())
                        )

            )
            .subscribe(
                null,
                null,
                () -> log.info("done data initialization...")
            );
    }

}
```

The **subscribe** caused this exception.

The [source code](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/data-mongo-transaction) is pushed to my github.

I just replace the content of DataInitializer with the new **mongoTemplate.inTransaction()**.

PS: I used the latest Mongo in a Docker container to serve the mongodb service, at the moment, it was 4.0.1. The Docker console shows:

```
mongodb_1    | 2018-08-20T15:56:04.434+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
mongodb_1    | 2018-08-20T15:56:04.447+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=12635c1c3d2d
mongodb_1    | 2018-08-20T15:56:04.447+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.1
mongodb_1    | 2018-08-20T15:56:04.448+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 54f1582fc6eb01de4d4c42f26fc133e623f065fb
```

**UPDATE:** When I tried to start up Mongo servers as Replica Set via a [Docker Compose file](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/mongo-rep-set.yml):

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    container_name: localmongo1
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
  mongo2:
    hostname: mongo2
    container_name: localmongo2
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
  mongo3:
    hostname: mongo3
    container_name: localmongo3
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - "27019:27017"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
```

And change the Mongo uri string to:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/blog
```

Then got the failure info like:

```
11:08:20.845 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - No server chosen by com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$1@796d3c9f from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN,
```

Comment: the client claims that "Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected"; could you check the version of your mongo instances?

Comment: @BrianClozel I am sure, Mongo version is 4.0.1. I have updated my original post.

Comment: Make sure to run MongoDB as Replica Set, see also https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-replica-sets.

Comment: @mp911de Updated my post, not sure if need extra setting to make it work.

Comment: @Hantsy please try to add the replica set option (`replicaSet=rs0`) to the URI. By doing so the client is put in an node autodetect mode. Please also check if you've initialized the replica set correctly, via the `rs.initiate({ _id: "rs0", members: [ { _id: 0, host: ...` command.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl Added **replicaSet=rs0** to mongo uri, in the console, the TYPE was set to REPLICA_SET, not sure if this is a host name problem now. I am using Docker compose to run these mongo servers in a Docker machine(vituralbox), in my application, I set the uri addresses as **localhost:portNum** (all ports are mapped to my host machine). It seems  it can not be recognized.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl I got info in the application log like this when run my application, **INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Server localhost:27017 does not appear to be a member of an initiated replica set.**

Comment: that pretty much looks like the replica set never got initialized. Make sure you've run [the initialization sequence](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#initiate-the-replica-set) before you connect with your application.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl I used a script file to initialize it, check it [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/mongo-initdb.d/mongo-rs-init.js), and I set it under **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** folder in a docker container which will be executed automatically,  but I am not sure if Mongo replica sets recognize these servers via  the settings in init js(host name in dockers), or can scan the servers via IPs(settings in my codes).